# Laravel validator unique except user id not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a settings form where users can update their info.

My validation code looks like

```
    $rules = array(
        'active'    => 'required',
        'email'     => 'email',
        'username'  => "required|alphaNum|unique:users,username,{{$id}}",
        'password'  => 'sometimes|min:3'
    );
```

`$id` contains the user id of the current user.

But I keep getting the `The username has already been taken.` error message when the `username` value is the current username of the user.

I also tried the line as `'username'    => "required|alphaNum|unique:users,username,".$id,`

Comment: By looking at the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique) it seems `,".$id` is the correct way of doing it. But the column you are comparing it against is the username, not the user id.

Answer (score 0):

To embed variables into a string you must use `"` double quotes:

```
$rules = array(
    'active'    => 'required',
    'email'     => 'email',
    'username'  => "required|alphaNum|unique:users,username,{{$id}}",
    'password'  => 'sometimes|min:3'
);
```

Comment: Hi, even with double quotes it also returns that the username is taken.

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast string to the $id, so it is:

`'username' => "required|alphaNum|unique:users,username,".(string)$id,`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a primaryKey as varchar. It is important, that the given $id has no spaces (trimmed) . That held me up several hours to find this out..